# How to remove the margins/ borders from transparent java swing table

Tags: java, swing

Hello i want to remove the border of scrollablepane so that it will create illusion that this table automatically adjusts itself according to data.

```
BrowserTable.getTableHeader().setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 14));
    BrowserTable.setModel(dtm);
    BrowserTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(150);
    BrowserTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMaxWidth(150);
    BrowserTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(470);
    BrowserTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setMaxWidth(470);
    BrowserPane.getViewport().setOpaque(false);
    BrowserPane.getViewport().setBorder(null);
    //BrowserTable.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
    BrowserPane.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
    BrowserTable.setShowGrid(false);
    BrowserTable.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
```

Also BrowserTable.setOpaque is false here.

Output:[[image: 1]]

Comment: You could set the bordercolor to the same color as the panel which lays under it.

Comment: kinda works thanks..

Comment: 1) Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. 2) `scrollPane.setBorder(null)`